# Remove sending order emails from magento cron

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9.1 and `after placing some orders`, `no transaction email` was send ( like in Magento 1.8 ). I've figured out, that transaction emails are send using the magento cron.

Is there a way, to send the mails after placing them?

So i don't want to use the magento cron.

Comment: Who voted -1 explain your position. I think it's normal question.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1

Comment: @zhartaunik normal question for the Q&A magento you shared there, but you are here on Stack Overflow, where the scope is different. Since this question does not show any sign of research nor any line of code, it does clearly not stands as a good question in Stack Overflow scope. Down voting does not imply that a question is not good or not relevant, it does imply that a question does not meets the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) standards of this (and maybe only this) part of stack exchange network.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Please delete this question and post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Magento cron, the only other way to send a new order email is to go to the order view in the Magento admin, and click Send Email. This will send the email if the email_sent flag on the order (in sales_flat_order) has not already been set.